# How do I Handle tokens within text blocks in JavaCC?

Tags: java, javacc

I have a simple aspect of a DSL where I can define a key and a value as such:

> ```
> mykey=\
>    This is my $REF{useful}
>    multiline
>    string
>    where I terminate with a backslash
>    but I support escaped \\ characters
>    and I wish to handle the value part of this string
>    as 3 blocks in this example.
> \
> ```

The three tokens (for the value part) I would like in this example are

- ValueLiteral == This is my
- ValueReference == $REF{useful}
- ValueLiteral ==     multiline etc....

I defined a rule for the value as such:

```
void multiLineValue(): {} {
  < BACKSLASH >< EOL >
  (
    valuePartLiteralMulti() |
    valuePartRef()
  )*
  < BACKSLASH >
}
```

Here is my TOKEN definition for the multiline string type:

```
TOKEN :
{
     < MULTILINE_STRING:(  ( (~["\\"])
    | ("\\"
        ( ["\\", "'", "\"", "$", "n", "r", "t", "b", "f"]
        | ["u", "U"]["+"]["0"-"9","a"-"f","A"-"F"]["0"-"9","a"-"f","A"-"F"]["0"-"9","a"-"f","A"-"F"]["0"-"9","a"-"f","A"-"F"]
        )
      ) ))+>
}
```

My problem is that my multi line string token type also consumes the character sequence of the '$REF{' characters.

I would like to modify this multi-line string so that it will stop consuming characters when it encounters an unescaped "$REF{" (but will continue reading past a "\$REF{" sequence).

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but in your token definition you also include $ (in unicode?), maybe you should add ~("$") (or the unicode equivalent) at the beginnig.

Or you can use syntatic LOOKAHEAD, something like LOOKAHEAD(valuePartRef())...

p.s. Can you have more than one REF?